# Dual booting windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

So i Want to upgrade my windows 7 to windows 8 
Thing is holding me back is the ability to dual boot. will I be able to dual boot with windows 8 as i were with 7, can I install 8 and ubuntu 12.10 and select at the boot menu as I were able in windows 7

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but i am pretty sure it will work just fine.

Just remember that installing Windows 8 while having Ubuntu will override the grub and install the Windows boot manager. But you can re-install grub by booting from Ubuntu live cd/usb.

I've heard that Microsoft will work on making it hard to dual-boot with other OSs in future computers, but for now you are safe :)

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot