# How do I fix dual boot startup for Ubuntu installation on Windows 8 Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-8

I have a Lenovo laptop with preinstalled windows 8 64bit- I attempted installation of Ubuntu 13.04 - however after installation I was faced with the GRUB loader. From the Grub loader if I try to start up the Windows Loader option it wouldn't load windows 8 and instead show me an EFI file missing error.

Alternatively if I restart the laptop and click F12 key I get to the Bootloader screen where I can choose to boot either:

```
Ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager
EFI DVD/CD ROM
EFI USB
```

This is the only way I can choose to enter into either windows or Ubuntu plus after installing Ubuntu I've noticed that I now have a new unrecognised file format partition on windows 8 - I'm assuming its the Ubuntu partition.

The question is that how can I set up a dual boot screen that actually works here so I can choose to boot either windows 8 or Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? In UEFI mode? Try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Note down the link it provides you in the end so that you can give it to us if boot repair doesn't fix your problems.

Comment: Not sure what mode it was though - I just rebooted the system and selected to boot from the CD at the BIOS screen. Then ran a normal install i.e install Ubuntu Alongside Windows

Comment: You assume correctly that the partition Windows doesn't recognize is likely the Ubuntu partition. It seems there a a couple of ways you can do that. You can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207789/dual-booting-windows-8 or this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager